# How to use low pass filter in Matlab for discrete data?

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter

[image: This data has noise, I want to apply a low-pass filter to it. How to design it and apply it?]

As see in the picture, there are high frequency noise in the signal. How to design a low-pass filter to eliminate the noise? How to apply this filter in Matlab?

Comment: This is a MATLAB programming question and thus off-topic for this stackexchange site.

Comment: Not sure which "noise" you're referring to, but what I see is highly systematic. Are you sure you're not having an error in your data acquisition?

Answer (score 1):

Check [conv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) function. Use `conv(f,x)` where `f` is the filter and `x` is the signal.

You can also implement the filter process in frequency domain:

```
X=fft(x);
F=fft(f);
X_LP=real(ifft(X.*F));
```

You can use [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) too. In `y = filter(b,a,x)`, the filter is described by numerator coefficient vector `b` and denominator coefficient vector `a`,which is different in `conv` where the input is the time series of the filter. But `conv(f,x)` and `filter(f,1,x)` gives the same result in your case.

**EDIT**

For dfilt.dffir type filter, use the code below ([example page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/filter.html)):

```
x = randn(100,1);    % Original signal.
b = fir1(50,.4);     % 50th-order linear-phase FIR filter.
hd = dfilt.dffir(b);    % Direct-form FIR implementation.
y = filter(hd,x);
```

`filter` can handle FIR and IIR systems, while `conv` only works for FIR filter.

Besides,  `filter` can also return the filter states, so that it can be used in subsequent calls without incurring filter transients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't use this function. The error message is "Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'dfilt.dffir'." and I can use "filter" function. What's the difference of "conv" and "filter"?

Comment: convert your signal and filter to double by double(x) and double(f) before using conv

Comment: see my update in answer for difference between filter and conv

Comment: Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'dfilt.dffir'. this is what I got when I tried to fft the filter

Comment: What do

"which fft" and
"whos fft"

return?

Comment: built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/datafun/@logical/fft)  % logical method and we didn't get any return for 'whos fft'

Comment: that sounds strange to me....what's the data type of your filter? is it a double 1D vector?

Comment: The type of the filter is "dfilt.dffir", not a 1D vector. Maybe my design of filter is wrong. Could you give me some suggestions on which filter (method) to choose?

Comment: see my update in the answer please.

Comment: ok it seems to be able to work! thanks! but the result was not so feasible, maybe the parameter of the filter is not accurate. The amplitude of noise is decreasing but not totally and the filtered signal shifts to right. The noise frequency is 28Hz and the signal is 0.4Hz

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/72105  this post might help for the shift problem. for your reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the picture displayed the filter or the signal?
If your filter is saved in the SOS-format (second order system) and you have the dsp-toolbox, you can use the sosfilt or filtfilt function.

Comment: It's the signal. What's your suggestion on filter design?